# Finding a repeated string with grep and "bounds"

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a file `test-matching.txt` that looks like this:

```
ba
bababa
baba
babadooba
```

According to the grep man page, I should be able to get all but the first line using the expression

```
grep "ba{2,}" test-matching.txt
```

This should match all the lines containing instances of a string with 2 or more "ba's". However, when I run it, I get no output.

---

First I tried `grep "ba" test-matching.txt` just to make sure it was working at all, and it gave me all four lines as output.

I've also tried the following, each with no output:

- With the -e option: `grep -e "ba{2,}" test-matching.txt`
- With the -e option and single quotes: `grep -e 'ba{2,}' test-matching.txt`
- With the -e option and escaped braces: `grep -e "ba\{2,\}" test-matching.txt`
- Without the -e option and single quotes: `grep 'ba{2,}' test-matching.txt`
- Without the -e option and escaped braces: `grep "ba\{2,\}" test-matching.txt`
- With {2} instead of {2,}: `grep -e 'ba{2}' test-matching.txt`
- With {2} instead of {2,} and the -e option: `grep -e 'ba{2} test-matching.txt`
- etc.

What is the correct way match all the lines of "ba" concatenated 2 or more times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `egrep` or `grep -E` (not `grep -e`) if you want to use Extended regular expression syntax. If you want to use basic regular expression syntax, you need to backslash-escape the braces. Finally, if you want to repeat `ba`, you need to group: `egrep '(ba){2,}'`,  or `grep '\(ba\)\{2,\}'` if you prefer using basic regular expressions.

Comment: I think you might have the `""` and `''` backwards, since `"\$"` evaluates to `$` while `'\$'` evaluates to `\$`.

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius: Precisely. For the `grep` to see the `\{`, you need to version which evaluates to `\{`

Comment: Oh, does `grep` need to see the `\{` though? This by itself worked for me: `egrep "(ba){2,}"`.

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius: egrep does not want the backslashes. grep does. (But I removed the erroneous comment about double and single quotes, since both of them will pass \{ through.)

Comment: How weird... You're right of course, I'm just confused as to why that would be the case.

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius: Historic reasons, and back-compatibility. Extended regular expressions are better, and BREs should die. But they won't because they were around first and no-one knows how many mission-critical shell scripts would break if the default were changed. My advice: just use egrep all the time.

Answer (score 2):

`ba{2,}` hits only the `a`

```
baa
baaa
baaaa
etc
```

You need `(ba){2,}` to make it works on group.

Try:

```
egrep "(ba){2,}" file
```

or

```
grep "\(ba\)\{2,\}" file
bababa
baba
babadooba
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem. You and rici seem to be feeding off of each other's answers - it's gonna be hard to pick which one should get the check. :P

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius For me credit is not important, you can just give +1 :)

Comment: Ahaha, nice reverse psychology there. +1'd.